# How does __call__ method arguments type inference work?

Tags: python, pycharm, type-inference

I was looking through the `argparse` python module and saw following code:

```
class Action(_AttributeHolder):
    """Information about how to convert command line strings to Python objects.
    ...
    """

    def __init__(self,
                 option_strings,
                 dest,
                 nargs=None,
                 const=None,
                 default=None,
                 type=None,
                 choices=None,
                 required=False,
                 help=None,
                 metavar=None):
        self.option_strings = option_strings
        self.dest = dest
        self.nargs = nargs
        self.const = const
        self.default = default
        self.type = type
        self.choices = choices
        self.required = required
        self.help = help
        self.metavar = metavar

    def _get_kwargs(self):
        names = [
            'option_strings',
            'dest',
            'nargs',
            'const',
            'default',
            'type',
            'choices',
            'help',
            'metavar',
        ]
        return [(name, getattr(self, name)) for name in names]

    def __call__(self, parser, namespace, values, option_string=None):
        raise NotImplementedError(_('.__call__() not defined'))
```

I am using pycharm as my IDE and if i mouse over the `__call__` method I get the follwoing info:

[image]

Now usually i use type-hinting to confer this, but where is the hinting done here?

Can someone explain me how does pycharm know the types of these arguments? and where do these even come from? they are not defined in the class `Action` nor its parent `_AttributeHolder` (which itself is derived from object) nor anywhere in the module itself.

Comment: [Separate stub file.](https://github.com/python/typeshed/blob/master/stdlib/argparse.pyi)

Comment: It just infers from the use you may have in the code, like most type warnings.